# Question related to google authentication flow in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

Okay, I will go crazy if someone doesn't explain to me what is going wrong. Its whether too simple or I am too stupid.

Here's the code, feel free to copy-paste it in your machines and **RUN IT MORE THAN ONCE WITHOUT RESTARTING THE SERVER. I REPEAT, DO NOT RESTART THE SERVER.**

```
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library');
const router = require('express')();
const open = require('open');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const { Buffer } = require('node:buffer');
var stream = require('stream');

const { redirect_uris, client_id, client_secret } = require('./config/config');

const filePath = path.join(__dirname + '/output/image.png');

async function pushToDrive(req, res) {
    try {
        const oAuth2Client = await getAuthenticatedClient();
        console.log("zero")
        // After acquiring an access_token, you may want to check on the audience, expiration,
        // or original scopes requested.  You can do that with the `getTokenInfo` method.
        // const tokenInfo = await oAuth2Client.getTokenInfo(
        //     oAuth2Client.credentials.access_token
        // );
        const drive = google.drive({
            version: 'v3',
            auth: oAuth2Client,
        });
        console.log("first")

        const response = await drive.files.create({
            resource: {
                mimeType: 'image/png'
            },
            media: {
                // mimeType: 'application/pdf',
                body: fs.createReadStream(filePath)
            },
            fields: 'id'
        });
        console.log("second")
        console.log(response.data.id);
        res.send(response.data.id);
        // return response.data.id;

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

/**
* Create a new OAuth2Client, and go through the OAuth2 content
* workflow.  Return the full client to the callback.
*/
function getAuthenticatedClient() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // create an oAuth client to authorize the API call.  Secrets are kept in a `keys.json` file,
        // which should be downloaded from the Google Developers Console.
        try {
            const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(
                client_id,
                client_secret,
                redirect_uris
            );

            // Generate the url that will be used for the consent dialog.
            const authorizeUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
                access_type: 'offline',
                scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
            });

            open(authorizeUrl, { wait: false }).then(cp => cp.unref());

            router.get('/oauthcallback', async (req, res) => {
                // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/info.html'));
                // Now that we have the code, use that to acquire tokens.
                const r = await oAuth2Client.getToken(req.query.code);
                // Make sure to set the credentials on the OAuth2 client.
                oAuth2Client.setCredentials(r.tokens);
                console.info('Tokens acquired.');
                resolve(oAuth2Client);
                console.log("here2");
                res.send("You are authenticated");
                res.end();
                return resolve(oAuth2Client); 
            });
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }

    });
}

router.get('/xyz', pushToDrive);
router.listen(5000);

// pushToDrive();

// module.exports = { pushToDrive, getAuthenticatedClient, router };
```

The output I get in my backend console ->

```
Tokens acquired.
here2
zero
first
second
1rVk4Jjm0h_tO-x-BIDm1iWVDzZ4KfEJ3
Tokens acquired.
here2
Tokens acquired.
here2
```

As you can see, I got the file_id once - the first time I ran through the Drive upload. That's a success. But any subsequent tries stop at the resolution of `oAuth2Client`. **WHY?** If its the event loop, then someone explain me why its not returning control to the parent function. From running the debugger, I found out that Nodejs...just stops at `resolve(oAuth2Client)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes in your code:
<s>1. You cannot define route inside another route. Your function `pushToDrive` which you call inside `/xyz` route defines new route to `/oauthcallback`.</s>
Sorry, you can - only have to take care the routes are called in proper sequence.

2. Calling whatever after `resolve` in `new Promise` is a bit problematic, as it is called right after the whole function is started - it does not wait until something calls the `promise.resolve`

I would try something like this:

app.js

```
const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(
                client_id,
                client_secret,
                redirect_uris
            );

const authorizeClient = () => {
            const authorizeUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
                access_type: 'offline',
                scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
            });
            open(authorizeUrl, { wait: false }).then(cp => cp.unref());


async function pushToDrive(req, res) {
    try {
        const drive = google.drive({
            version: 'v3',
            auth: oAuth2Client,
        });
        console.log("first")

        const response = await drive.files.create({
            resource: {
                mimeType: 'image/png'
            },
            media: {
                // mimeType: 'application/pdf',
                body: fs.createReadStream(filePath)
            },
            fields: 'id'
        });
        console.log("second")
        console.log(response.data.id);
        res.send(response.data.id);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

router.get('/oauthcallback', async (req, res) => {
                const r = await 
                oAuth2Client.getToken(req.query.code);
                oAuth2Client.setCredentials(r.tokens);
                console.info('Tokens acquired.');
            });

router.get('/xyz', pushToDrive);
router.listen(5000);
```

Comment: Hm. I see what you are saying. Good news - I used a whole different approach to upload files so this is not a problem anymore. But academically, I would like to know the potential problem. As for what you pointed out -
1) Fair point. Never thought of it that way, the official documents used plain ol' Node for defining routes. I just translated the logic to express. Think this will also be a problem if I used 'nested routes' in vanilla node as well?

Comment: 2) This second part is picked up from the documentation, so I am not sure how I could change this. I had actually tried to replace `new Promise` with `async`, but it was not working as expected so I had to revert back to this.